# Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Im rather new to working with TS and is having some trouble resolving an issue TS is shouting at me about.

```
Type '(x: boolean) => void' is not assignable to type '(e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'x' and 'e' are incompatible.
    Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)
OpenNavBar.tsx(11, 3): The expected type comes from property 'toggleHandler' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }
```

I am making a navbar, and the hamburger menu on mobile opens with React Spring. As you can see a usestate to keep tabs on whether the menu is open or not. The toggle handler that is passed to the  OpenNavBar component switched this state from true to false and vice versa. The code is as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationLinks } from '../constants';
import Link from 'next/link';
import * as S from './styles';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { RiMenu5Fill } from 'react-icons/ri';
import OpenNavBar from './OpenNavBar';

const Navbar: React.FC = () => {
  const [mobileMenuIsOpen, setMobileMenuIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const toggleHandler = (x: boolean) => {
    setMobileMenuIsOpen(!x);
  };
  return (
    <S.Header>
      <S.Nav>
        <S.Logo>Kishokanth.com</S.Logo>
        <S.Navigation>
          {NavigationLinks.map((link) => (
            <Link href={link.destination} key={uuidv4()}>
              <a>{link.destination}</a>
            </Link>
          ))}
          <Link href="contact">
            <S.Button>Let's Talk</S.Button>
          </Link>
        </S.Navigation>
        <S.MobileNavigation>
          <RiMenu5Fill onClick={() => setMobileMenuIsOpen(!mobileMenuIsOpen)} />
          <OpenNavBar toggle={mobileMenuIsOpen} toggleHandler={toggleHandler} />
        </S.MobileNavigation>
      </S.Nav>
    </S.Header>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

The OpenNavBar component I work with looks like

```
import React from 'react';
import { animated, useSpring } from 'react-spring';
import { AiOutlineClose } from 'react-icons/ai';
import Link from 'next/link';
import * as S from './styles';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { MobileNavigationLinks } from '../constants';

interface Props {
  toggle: boolean;
  toggleHandler: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}

const OpenNavBar: React.FC<Props> = ({ toggle, toggleHandler }) => {
  const { x } = useSpring({
    x: toggle ? 0 : 100,
  });
  return (
    <animated.nav
      style={{
        transform: x.interpolate((x) => `translate3d(${x * -1}%, 0,0)`),
        position: 'fixed',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        color: 'white',
        top: '0',
        bottom: '0',
        left: '0',
        right: '0',
        zIndex: '1',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <S.UL>
        {MobileNavigationLinks.map((link) => (
          <li key={uuidv4()}>
            <Link href={`/${link.destination}`}>
              <a
                onClick={() => toggleHandler(toggle)}
                style={{ marginTop: '3rem' }}
              >
                {link.destination}
              </a>
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
        <li>
          <AiOutlineClose
            onClick={() => toggleHandler(toggle)}
            style={{ marginTop: '3rem' }}
          />
        </li>
      </S.UL>
    </animated.nav>
  );
};

export default OpenNavBar;
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only issue appears to be in `OpenNavBar` `Props` interface declaration. Your `toggleHandler` needs to take a `boolean` as the argument.

```js
interface Props {
  toggle: boolean;
  toggleHandler: (x: boolean) => void;
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate, this worked. So am I correct in assuming that React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement> is for onchange events seen in forms and such?

Comment: Yeah, so if you were passing the function directly to a click handler you'd need to type the input as an event. For example, if it was `onClick={toggleHandler}` then `toggleHandler` would be taking the click event as an argument.